# Storing results from a for loop where the number of returns increases each iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm brand new to R. I've only been coding with it for a month or so.

What I am trying to do is generate and assign x and y coordinates for a growing/spreading population at each time step using a for loop.

The problem I'm having is storing the returned x and y outputs from the for loop. Key issue is that the number of returns increases with each iteration and I would like them stored at each time step. For example, at T0 there is one return and at T20 there are 496.

I have tried creating a lattice, arrays, data frames, etc. Everything I have found online hasn't helped.

```
set.seed(29807)
Adults <- allYears[3,]                     # Adult tree population yrs 1:20
Time <- 21
dist <- abs(rnorm(Distance, mean = 51.5, sd = 63))  # dispersal distribution
# Distance refers to the data table with 29807 distances.

# CREATE A FOR LOOP WHERE YOU DRAW X NUMBER OF DISTANCES EQUIVALENT TO THE NUM OF ADULTS AT THAT TIME STEP

for (i in 1:Time) {                                            
  N <- sample(dist, size = round(Adults[i]), replace = FALSE)  
  theta <- runif(N,0,2*pi)            # distance is assigned direction 
  x <- cos(theta)*N                   # assign variate a polar coordinate x
  y <- sin(theta)*N                   # assign variate a polar coordinate y
}
```

Comment: Try to use a list  to store the results and combine x and y in a dataframe e.g `... lst <- list();
for (i in 1:Time) {                                            
  N <- sample(dist, size = round(Adults[i]), replace = FALSE) 
  theta <- runif(N,0,2*pi)       
  lst[[i]] <- data.frame(x=cos(theta)*N, y=sin(theta)*N)       
}`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. I think my problem was that I was trying to create the storage outside of the for loop.